# Sitecore.NET 9.0.1 (rev. 171219) Form field reverts to a CMS login screen element

Tags: sitecore-forms

I have this strange bug in Sitecore Forms (DLL File Version 1.1.1.295) that occasionally causes a form to fail to render and display a screen like this:

[image]

This always occurs as I'm clicking and dragging form elements around a form. It will start as a single form element in a form looking like that, then the whole form becomes locked out. By "logging in" to this display I am greeted with the CMS login page in an infinite loop I can't login to. Nothing works until I restart the whole website.

Has anyone experienced something like this before?

EDIT: Answering Cristi's question through an edit because I am not allowed to comment yet. I loaded up the form in an incognito page (that's one way to temporarily solve the issue) I was able to add a text element and RawHtml element (from forms extensions) without any errors in the developer tools network tab.

Comment: Welcome to Sitecore Stack Exchange. Are you getting any errors in the developer tools  network tab when you are adding a new field? There should be a request to a url similar to this: /sitecore/api/forms/client/formfield/renderfield?fieldTypeId=

Comment: I think you might have an issue with your sitecore login cookie, can you try to delete your cookies from the browser, or if you can't try to remove only sitecore_userticket